# Return segmentation fault, after all code has been executed

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The following code is my solution to the cp problem in this link: http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=761

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    freopen("measurement.in","r",stdin);
    freopen("measurement.out","w",stdout);  

    vector<tuple<int,int,int>> records;
    
    int n; scanf("%d", &n);
    
    int day; char* cow; char sign; int change;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d %s %c%d", &day, cow, &sign, &change);
        
        if (sign == '-') change = -change;
        int id;
            
        if (strcmp(cow,"Bessie") == 0) id = 0;
        if (strcmp(cow,"Elsie") == 0) id = 1;
        if (strcmp(cow,"Mildred") == 0) id = 2;
    
        records.push_back(make_tuple(day,id,change)); 
    }

    sort(records.begin(),records.end());
    
    int galls[3] = {7,7,7};

    vector<int> board {0,1,2};  
    
    int num = 0;
    for (auto record : records){
        vector<int> temp = board;
        galls[get<1>(record)]+=get<2>(record);
        
        int max_o = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            max_o = max(max_o,galls[i]);
    
        board.clear();
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
            if (galls[i] == max_o) board.push_back(i);  

        if (board.size() != temp.size()){
            num++;
        } else{
            for (int i=0;i<board.size();i++){
                if (board[i] != temp[i]){
                    num++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << num;
}
```

This solution returns the correct value and all code is executed, but after all code is run, Segmentation fault (core dumped) is returned. I have never encountered a segmentation fault after all code has been executed so I a very confused as to why this is happening. Can someone help here?

This input file **measurement.in** is as follows:

```
4
7 Mildred +3
4 Elsie -1
9 Mildred -1
1 Bessie +2
```

Comment: [Don't use #include<bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: `char* cow` why is this a char *? Where is the space for this char* allocated or where is it initialized? Why are you using scanf() instead of `c++` iostreams?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with using the c-strings `strcmp` function. I used the string `compare` function instead and it worked!

Comment: I believe the bug is `char* cow` was never initialized. You have undefined behavior because of that. You should instead use `std::string` and not use scanf